# Download File using API Call in AppsScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to generate an invoice using data from my spreadsheet, and I'm not very familiar with HTTPS requests, let alone Google's UrlFetchApp. I'm trying to convert [this example code](https://github.com/Invoiced/invoice-generator.js/blob/master/invoice.js) provided by the API into something that AppsScript can use. So far it just saves the website as a .html to the folder.

```
function debug(){
  run();
}

const folderName = 'Invoices Test'

function generateInvoice(invoice) {
    var postData = JSON.stringify(invoice);
    var options = {
      'method'    : "post",
      'contentType': "application/json",
      'payload': postData
    };

    // Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('invoice-generator.com', options);
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
    var folderID = getInvoiceFolderID();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var result = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
}

/**
 * @return String
 */
function getInvoiceFolderID(){
  var id;

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  if(!folders.hasNext()){
    DriveApp.createFolder(folderName).getId();
  }
  else{
    id = folders.next().getId()
  }
  return id;
}

var invoice = {
    logo: "http://invoiced.com/img/logo-invoice.png",
    from: "Invoiced\n701 Brazos St\nAustin, TX 78748",
    to: "Johnny Appleseed",
    currency: "usd",
    number: "INV-0001",
    payment_terms: "Auto-Billed - Do Not Pay",
    items: [
        {
            name: "Subscription to Starter",
            quantity: 1,
            unit_cost: 50
        }
    ],
    fields: {
        tax: "%"
    },
    tax: 5,
    notes: "Thanks for being an awesome customer!",
    terms: "No need to submit payment. You will be auto-billed for this invoice."
}
```

Comment: What is the content of the html response from the API? Is there any error code returned?

Comment: the html response is just the webpage, like if I'm just doing a get for the URL. Response code is 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [full link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) in the `UrlFetchApp.fetch` parameter, as follows:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://invoice-generator.com', options);
```

This would return the correct response as a PDF:

[image]

Comment: wow, such a simple issue. you'd think UrlFetchApp would be smart enough to add that. Thanks for the help though lol